# Can I export as a legacy eps

Tags: export, eps

Can I export a file from Affinity Designer as a legacy eps (Illustrator 8) so I can use with Roland CutStudio?

Comment: Sorry Roland CutStudio

Comment: Do you know you can edit your question if you made a mistake. Just hit [Edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/162636/edit)

Comment: Well for obvious reasons its legacy only for illustrator.  But try running it through ghostscripts eps2eps command

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to try. I cannot test it, so it's only a guess.

Obviously you have already tried both available Postscript language options in EPS export and they didn't work. The reason may be CutStudio Expects the original Postscript. Or you have something else which is not allowed in CutStudio.

I guess you have seen an error message which says that your EPS is not compatible with Illustrator 8 and it didn't give any hint what's actually wrong, only something that Illustrator 8 wouldn't output - maybe too new Postscript language level or some drawing item which is OK in Affinity D, but never exist in Illustrator 8 EPS exports.

CutStudio support page tells that quite a limited set of things are allowed in a file imported from Adobe Illustrator. But the file can be in AI format. There's a list what features can be included. Read it carefully!

Export as PDF, try older PDF versions and change the filename extension from PDF to AI.

This export

[image]

generates a PDF which can be opened in legacy Illustrator with no questions "this is a PDF, how do you exactly want to convert to AI?" It uses the PDF format of Adobe Acrobat 5.

The shape contains nothing else but a single curves layer (a path) with a stroke and fill, everything as a single object. It's not a group nor a non-destructive combination. Be sure your export doesn't contain anything which must be rasterized for PDF or is not allowed in CutStudio's import from AI feature list.

Try something this simple also with the available EPS export Postscript language options. I'm afraid it will not work, because I have seen some indirect hints (zero explicit facts found anywhere) that Illustrator 8 used the oldest available Postscript language in EPS exports. Affinity offers only Postscript levels 2 and 3 which are much later products. The found indirect hints do not exclude the possibility that Illustrator 8 could also export EPS files with Postscript level 2.